# How to search content of other website and retrieve the result and place in our Android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am developing an Android app. I want to search the contents of other website and retrieve the result and display the same if it matches the search criteria.

Ex: I have two website : abc.com with product pro1 and pro2 
                     and xyz.com with product pro1 and pro3

Now if I search for pro1 in my app I should get URL of the pro1 with min data like specification, date of release etc. as a result which I will display in my app as

2 results found:

1. abc.com
2. xyz.com

And I will make results clickable so that they will open in mobile browser.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where does the search run? If it's on the server it's nothing to do with Andriod, just have your sever-side script search both sites. If the search runs on the Android device, build a "database" that contains products from both sites.

Comment: my problem is i don know how to go forward with my problem. i don know wat is the solution or by wat means i can solve my problem. i don have knowlwdge of back-end. post some appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic question, so I will answer with a generic answer.

It sounds like what you are looking to do is run a search on an existing website using their existing search framework.

What you have to figure out is:

1. Does the site(s) have an existing externalized framework?  For instance, Google provides a VERY extensive set of libraries to perform all sorts of "magic" in several different languages, including Java.  Other sites may have some sort of Web Service API available to do searches on their site.  You will have to investigate this on your part, as the possibilities are truly endless.
2. Is there an existing "search" feature on the site in question?  If so, then you can always "brute force" it by figuring out what their search form posts/puts, then simulated it using HttpClient or some other means in Java.  You will then have to brute-force parse out the results.  You may even want to read #3
3. Do you have to search the site yourself?  If so, you're probably better off having some sort of server process doing the "searches", and aggregating them into some easily called web service your app can call.

That's the best answer I can give you.  There is not "standard" way to do searches, outside of them being implemented using HTML Forms from a web page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i think i am able to understand you point..i don have local data base. i need to get it from there server. question is how..i know v can use XML service request having parameter name n userdata. Upon sending the request v get a XML reply having our quarried data. is my understanding correct? or do v have some other simpler method to do the same

Comment: Without knowing specifically what site your referring too, its very hard to say.  And I am not an Android developer at all, but I know Java quite well.  But from your response, it sounds like there is some XML-driven web service available.  Again, there are thousands of ways to do this, from taking the WSDL and generating a Java client to brute-forcing it by dummying up a regular HTTP call (I believe the class is HTTPConnection), and thousands of other variations.  All of these approaches have their plus and minuses.

Comment: Thank you 1ce again. please provide me with a example code of doing it if you can. i am trying to access ebay kind of website. let me know a suitable variation. i will work on it. :)

Comment: I can't write your code for you, and saying "its an ebay type site" is not enough information to go on.  Unfortunately, to do what you are asking, will require some knowledge of how web pages work, and how one can interface with them.  At a high-level, I would suggest reading about ws4j if your interfacing site has some sort of web service UI, java.net.HttpURLConnection for brute-force method.  If you had a more specific example, I might be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: thank you 1ce again. i am totally new to this concept. i will tell you wat i am trying to do. consider an app n wesite like Ebay. my aim is to search produts on ebay and present it in my app. i will provide fields like category,new,old,price range and send the request. then i will receive my queried data . publish it in app if such product really exits.my concern is how to send the request n receive the reply. remaining i know how to go forward with UI n logical part.